# How to save output to file after editing with AudioKit framework?

Tags: xcode, swift, audio, swift2, audiokit

I'm making application, where I have `UITableView` with audio files, previously recorded by `AVFoundation`. After selecting one, I'm editing the file with audio effects from `AudioKit` framework. My question is: how can I save the `AudioKit.output` to my tableview after all changes I made (it can even be saved as the same file) ?